# Validate Date time through laravel Validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to validate date time through Laravel Validation like this:

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'DateTime'=> 'required|after_or_equal:' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
]);
```

I want to restrict the user if they enter date time greater than current date time but in my case date is being validated but i have to validate time also. Format of date time is `2020-12-23 17:40:00`

Comment: Just to confirm, should validation **fail** if it's in the future?

Comment: @Rwd: It should not allow user to enter previous dates, future dates (with time also) are allowed in my case

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$this->validate($request,[
        'DateTime'=> 'required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|after_or_equal:' . date(DATE_ATOM),
]);
```

And if you want to change the time you can do sth like this:

```
'request_date'=>'after:'.date(DATE_ATOM, time() + (5 * 60 * 60)),
```

Or

```
'request_date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|after:5 hours'
```

Comment: :Thanks for the answer, I have tried your solution but it is allowing me to enter previous time, my system time is 17:00 and i'm entering 15:00 then also it is allowing it should restrict from entering past dates

Comment: Thanks it is working now, will it work same on local and serve or i have to change it on server

Answer (score -1):

In addition to other response, is good to know that Laravel don't have a validator for timestamp. If you want to use it, I recommend something like:

```
'timestamp' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1', 'digits:10'],
```

Then in your code you can verified which date the input makes reference

Comment: This will break in 2286. :-p

Comment: Is a point... I don't know if is a real problem. Maybe can change to digits:11